# Python Triple-quoted strings with variable

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, variables

Trying to `write` to a file with variables, but that is returning error:

```
template = """1st header line
second header line
There are people in rooms
and the %s
"""
with  open('test','w') as myfile:
    myfile.write(template.format()) % (variable)
```

Comment: What problem do you have? The only problem I see is that you haven't defined `variable`, which I assume is a code shrinkage problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.format` method](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) expects you to template the blanks to be filled in your string with the `{}`-style, not `%s`. It also expects the interpolated values to be given as its arguments.

```
template = """1st header line
second header line
There are people in rooms
and the {}
"""

myfile.write(template.format(variable))
```

Answer (score 1):

The given string literal is [printf-style string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting). Use `str % arg`:

```
with  open('test', 'w') as myfile:
    myfile.write(template % variable)
```

To use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), you should use placeholder `{}` or `{0}` instead of `%s`.

Answer (score 1):

### The Error

`myfile.write(template.format())` returns nothing to which you are using `%` operator to concatenate

### Minimal Edit

You can perfectly use `%s` .The problem is you mismatched parenthesis and the parenthesis i.e. `)` should be after your variable as in `myfile.write(template.format() % (variable))`. But as `template.format()` is *redundant*, it can be ignored. Thus the **correct way** is

```
myfile.write(template % (variable))
```

**Note**:- Any string with an empty `format()` and no `{}` in the string returns the string itself

Comment: @hyades That's what I said